# Cross correlation coefficient using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, wavelet

Actually I want to calculate the cross correlation coefficient of any signal on comparing with all mother wavelets like Morlet, Daubechies using MATLAB.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific and if possible post some pseudo-code?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking. Are you cross correlating only with mother wavelets or taking a wavelet transform using each mother wavelet and then cross-correlating the results?

Comment: Yes I am cross correlating only with the mother wavelets. Actually I want to find out which of the mother wavelets will match best to my input signal.

Comment: how did solve your problem? I also have problem in this, could you please tell me how to solve it? Thank you.

Comment: @James Please do NOT use answers to ask questions. I've converted it to a comment.